# Pentaho - how to manage time dimension

Tags: pentaho, business-intelligence

I am using Pentaho Enterprise to get a reporting view on helpdesk activity.
I have created my schema + cube with dimensions and measures, but I am wondering how to deal with time dimension.

Typicially : I have issue creation date and closing date.
I would like to build a report with projects in row, time (year/month) in column, and use both "number of created tickets" & "number of closed tickets" per project/month.

I have designed dimensions "Creation date" (foreign key on issue_creation_date) and "Closing date" (fk on issue_closing_date), I have a "Issue count" measure (count(issue_id)), but I have no idea how to link my dimensions with an "abstract" time dimension which will automatically use the good join.

Is it possible at all ? If so, how can I do it ?

And if you have good tutorials on how to build cubes, thank you (I found some but they were based on too simple cubes).

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Is there a way to do this within BA server as some type of formula/derived field rather than through a formal schema change/design? I mean through the web interface, not through modifying the xml or kettle.